# Using Picasso with ImageView

Tags: android

I'm looking through the [Grid View doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html), and I wanted to see if I can display images from online instead of the ones in the local res directory.

I set up Picasso based on the doc, and decided to try to implement Picasso into imageView like so (the code below is taken from the GridVIew doc example)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5w9Z.jpg").into(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }
```

I wanted this should return to me [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5w9Z.jpg) to try it out, but it on my device it's not returning any images.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If not, try enabling logging on your `Picasso` object: `Picasso.with(mContext).setLoggingEnabled(true).load(url).into(imageView);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe its time to do more debugging. As least it seems like the url does point to a valid image. So, maybe try some other things to figure out what is happening under the hood. For example:

- Ensure you have set the proper permission. 

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
- Set an error view holder to see request has come back and there is an error
  `Picasso.with(mContext).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").error(R.drawable.error_holder).into(imageView);`
- Enable debug indicator for Picasso. From [documentation](http://square.github.io/picasso/):

> For development you can enable the display of a colored ribbon which indicates the image source. Call setIndicatorsEnabled(true) on the Picasso instance.

Comment: For some reason the solution is two parts, first is to add the internet permission. Second is to pick any other image that is not a PNG file.